# PIC16F1933 Output pins not working

Tags: pic, assembly

I am having problems with getting certain pins on my microcontroller ([PIC16F1933](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41575C.pdf)) working as outputs. I have been simulating the code in Proteus Design Suite by Labcenter Electronics and it doesn't toggle all of the pins correctly which I am assuming is a problem with the code. The pins I am mostly having an issue with are PB1, PC0 & PC3. I have been through the datasheet and have tried to turn off all the peripherals that could be causing the problem but nothing seems to have solved it.

```
    LIST    p=16F1933           ; Tell assembler what chip we are using
include "P16F1933.inc"      ; Include the defaults for the chip

__CONFIG _CONFIG1, _FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _MCLRE_ON & _CP_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _BOREN_OFF & _CLKOUTEN_ON & _IESO_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF
__CONFIG _CONFIG2, _WRT_OFF & _VCAPEN_OFF & _PLLEN_OFF & _STVREN_ON & _BORV_19 & _LVP_ON

    ORG     0x0000           ; Processor reset vector 
    PAGESEL START 
    GOTO    START            ; When using debug header, first inst. 


ORG 0x0005 

START                            ; Turn on 16MHz OSC and select 8MHz 
    banksel OSCCON 
    bsf     OSCCON, IRCF3    ; 1110 = 8MHz HF   
    bsf     OSCCON, IRCF2  
    bsf     OSCCON, IRCF1  
    bcf     OSCCON, IRCF0  
    bsf     OSCCON, SCS1    ; Internal osc block 


                            ; Wait for the internal oscillator to stablise

    btfss   OSCSTAT, HFIOFS ; HFIOFS: stable (0.5%) 
    goto    OSCWAIT 

                            ; Initialize I/O pins
INITPIC

    movlw   b'00000000'     ; Least significant bits [3..0] to be set as outputs
    movwf   TRISA           ; Set as Port A lower four pins as output for L198 - 1
    movwf   TRISB           ; Set as Port B lower four pins as output for L198 - 2
    movwf   TRISC           ; Set as Port C lower four pins as output for LEDs
    movlw   b'00000000'     ; Set all pins to not be analogue inputs
    movwf   ANSELA          ; Set PORTA pins not be analogue input
    movwf   ANSELB          ; Set PORTB pins not be analogue input
    clrf    PORTA           ; Clear port A house keeping
    clrf    PORTB           ; Clear port B house keeping
    clrf    PORTC           ; Clear port C house keeping

    movlw   b'11111111'     ; Default OUTPUT
    movwf   LATA            ; Set intial output values of pins on port A to 0
    movwf   LATB            ; Set intial output values of pins on port B to 0
    movwf   LATC            ; Set intial output values of pins on port C to 0

LOOP
    movlw   b'11111111'     ; Output set one used to test port C
    movwf   LATA            ; Move test value to Port C output pins
    movwf   LATB            ; Move test value to Port C output pins
    movwf   LATC            ; Move test value to Port C output pins
    movlw   b'00000000'     ; Output set two used to test port C
    movwf   LATA            ; Move test value to Port C output pins
    movwf   LATB            ; Move test value to Port C output pins
    movwf   LATC            ; Move test value to Port C output pins
    goto    LOOP

END
```

All I am trying to do at the moment is get the pins to high/low with the relevant LAT register for each port.

Comment: Try to reduce your code to a minimal sample that is reproducing the error.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have taken out the delay and the code for portA and portB but it has not changed how the pins on portC change.

Comment: Providing a minimal reproducing code not only simplifying it for your debug, but also helps us to answer your question. Especially when it is about assembly..

Comment: I've removed the delay (which has had no effect) but I believe that everything else is necessary for the code to execute properly.

Comment: Can you step over the program?

Comment: @EugeneSh I don't think there's much left to remove, other than setting the configuration words within the MPLAB software and thus saving two lines of code.

Comment: @chaaaarlie2 The problem is solved as far as I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only looked at you code briefly, but your total disregard for the bank setting except for the one place you write to OSCCON may have something to do with your problem.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the cause of the issue as it seems to be solved when I added 'banksel LATC' before setting the latch values. I'm only just starting to use PICs as most of my experience is with stm32 in C.

Comment: Yep, you've switched to Bank 1 (probably) for OSCCON but never changed back. If you look at the PIC's function register table you'll see what bank contains which registers. The .inc file that you include simply translates register names (PORTA, TRISB, ANSEL, etc.) into numbers but doesn't take into account which bank that register is in. Therefore attempting to address PORTA from bank 1 will actually address TRISA (PORTx and TRISx are always the same register, except on adjacent banks.) Personally I find the BANKSEL command open to forgetfulness, even for experienced programmers.